# Solr doesn't suggest names with dot inside

Tags: solr, solr4, facet

I'm having some problems with the suggestion terms form solr.

I have indexed Titles eg. "foo.a123", "foo.a456"... if search for "foo" Solr returns me foo as a suggestions but if I search for "foo.a" no suggestions are given. The suggestion works properly if I search for 
"foo a".

I'm using the following configuration:

```
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="english/synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="english/stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />

            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="english/stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

The filed 'spell' is using the textSpell configuration

```
<field name="spell" type="textSpell" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="title" dest="spell"/>
<copyField source="subTitle" dest="spell"/>
<copyField source="content" dest="spell"/>
```

The 'spell' filed is used as facet.field and the facet.prefix in this example would be 'foo.a'

```
"facet_counts": {
"facet_queries": {},
"facet_fields": {
  "spell": []
},
"facet_dates": {},
"facet_ranges": {}
}
```

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: What does the analysis page say for content you're putting into the field? (The StandardFilterFactory [doesn't do anything in modern versions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Filter+Descriptions#FilterDescriptions-StandardFilter) of Solr, btw. - but removes `.` and `s` in earlier versions)

Comment: As I understand i recognizes the search term as one word. See https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVy9w.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the configuration is working as posted above.
The wordDelimeter would also work but is not necessary for my case. (The StandardFilterFactory just does nothing.)

I completely misunderstood the [stored="false"](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Common_field_options) option on the filed configuration. I expected the behavior of not need to re-write the document to the index but actually the flag defines if the filed is retrievable in the search result. Therefore I just need to re-index all the documents.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just use wordDelimiter filter https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_4_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/miscellaneous/WordDelimiterFilter.html

```
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" types="wdfftypes.txt" generateNumberParts="0" stemEnglishPossessive="0" splitOnCaseChange="1" preserveOriginal="1" catenateAll="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" generateWordParts="1" splitOnNumerics="1"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Actually the wordDelimeter isn't doing what i want. My problem is that I want to keep the Words with a dot inside as one string. I'm going to update the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
solr.StandardFilterFactory
```

> This filter is no longer operational in Solr when the luceneMatchVersion (in solrconfig.xml) is higher than "3.1".

In Solr 4.10.4 has `<luceneMatchVersion>4.10.4</luceneMatchVersion>`

So change the filter in you query analyzer